# Getting List of table and saving it to another table

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

So I got the rows and data from a table using jQuery and AJAX:

```
$("#btncopy").on("click", function () {
    //if ($tblRows.length !== 0) {
        var $tblRows = $("#tableRows>tr");
        var mainData = {};
        var detailData = [];


        $.each($tblRows, function (index, elem) {
            mainData.id = $(elem).find(".id").html();
            mainData.name = $(elem).find(".name").html();
            mainData.organization = $(elem).find(".organization").html();
            mainData.role_of = $(elem).find(".role_of").html();
            mainData.addedby = $(elem).find(".addedby").html();
            mainData.addedbyorg = $(elem).find(".addedbyorg").html();
            mainData.dated = $(elem).find(".dated").html();
            mainData.status_of = $(elem).find(".status_of").html();
            console.log(elem);
            detailData.push(mainData);
            mainData = {};


        });
        $.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'EmployeeAddNew',
            data: JSON.stringify({ detailData: detailData }),
            success: function (data) {

            },
            failure: function (response) {
                $('#result').html(response);
            }
        });
  //  }

});
```

I am getting all the data to my controller in an object:

[image: this is the data im getting from my table]
(sorry using mac wasn't able to take screenshot)

The question is how do I save this to another table as I'm stuck, I have no idea where to go from here as I'm new to MVC and I'm still learning. How do I save this to another table?

Comment: You want those detailData data to save to another table?

Comment: yessss thats what i need to do i have already created a table create stored procedures for it just dont know what to do to save it

Comment: You can check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save it on another table, create an instance of that object, populate its properties from your list, add it to dbContext, then save it (Assuming this is an Organization table or class):

```
foreach (var item in detailData)
{
    Organization obj = new Organization()
    {
        addedby = item.addedby,
        organization = item.organization
        //Populate your other properties here.
    } 
    _dbContext.Organization.Add(obj);
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Take note that saving is different from updating. If you want to update, remove the Add functionality, just update the property then call SaveChanges.

Comment: i think this will do thank you so much i was stuck in this for 3 days now before going online and asking it. Thankyou so much

Comment: Glad to help :) @AhsanBaloch